# How to call another function within the current function when both have same names but different signature?

Tags: c#, overloading

I have a situation like this:

```
public static SqlDataReader ReadFromDB(string inputSQLStatement)
{
    //Does some actual work here ..
}

public static DataTable ReadFromDB(string inputSQLStatement)
{
    return new DataTable().Load(ReadFromDB(inputSQLStatement));
}
```

basically the second function is trying to call another function with the same name as the calling function, but has a different return type ..

But with the above code, I get the following error on the return line in the second function:

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties ...
```

I thought maybe the compiler can figure out that the return from the second function is doing into a function which takes an SqlDataReader object, so it knows it has to call the version of ReadFromDB(), but I think I need to explicitly specify which version to call explicitly ..

So how can I tackle this ?

EDIT:

Nevermind, I found out my answer. Function overloading by return type is not supported in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: It's not a good pratice to have 2 methods with the same name and parameters. What's the purpuse of such design?

Answer (score 2):

Overloading by return type is not supported as the formal signature of a method doesn't include the return type but only the name of the method and the types of the parameters (Thanks to CAbbot).  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more info.
In this case you need to name the methods differently, for example:

```
public static SqlDataReader ReadFromDB(string inputSQLStatement)
{
    //Does some actual work here ..
}

public static DataTable ReadDataTableFromDB(string inputSQLStatement)
{
    return new DataTable().Load(ReadFromDB(inputSQLStatement));
}
```

Comment: +1 - I would add that a method's formal signature does not include the return type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @CAbbott: Thanks. I included it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The method signature is unique by its name, parameters length, then if the length is the same, then by their types (and when params is used, there is another situation). The idea is the return of the method does not count into the method signature.

So you will to rename the method, possible:

```
ReadFromDBIntoTable
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value does not belong to the signature. You could give the methods different names, like `ReadDataTableFromDB`, or move them to interfaces that you explicitly implement.